# Using external header file with definitions different from the ones used internally

Tags: c, libraries

Suppose you are writing a library that uses internally certain data structures, and wants to export to the user only a subset of them (or hide the exact type using something like `void *`). The definitions for all the structs and functions used in the library are in a header `library.h`, which will be used when building the library.

Is it considered good practice to also produce another copy of `library.h` that would not be used during the build process but only by users linking to the library?

For example suppose the library internally uses the following `library.h`:

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

struct myStruct {
    int some_x;
    void (*some_callback)(void);
};

typedef struct myStruct *myStruct_t;

#endif
```

While we would like to hide the definition of `myStruct` to the user, so we export a header `library.h` that is:

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

typedef void *myStruct_t;

#endif
```

Comment: You should consider having `library.h` and `library_impl.h` (or similar), with the latter #including the former.

Comment: I tend to organize my projects so that *public* headers are in an `include` subtree while *private* headers (like @OliverCharlesworth' suggestion `*_impl.h`) reside alongside the source files. Installation then only installs the public ones.

Comment: Additional suggestion: If you have *private functions* as well that are called across translation units of your library, but are not intended to be called by consuming code, google for symbol visibility -- gcc has for example `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`

Comment: Note: **never ever** `typedef` a pointer! And names ending with `_t` are reserved by certain standards extending the C standard, e.g. POSIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it considered good practice to also produce another copy of library.h that would not be used during the build process but only by users linking to the library?

No. While the details of a best practice for what you want to do are probably a matter of taste, delivering headers not used during building is objectively not a good practice: You risk to introduce typing errors that are never catched when you build your project.

So, without going into details on how you should organize that, what you should definitely do is have each "*private*" header `#include` the respective "*public*" header and not repeat public declarations in the private header. For your example, this would look e.g. like:

**library.h:**

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

typedef struct myStruct *myStruct_t;
// there's absolutely no need to use void * here. An incomplete struct
// type is perfectly fine as long as only pointers to it are used.

#endif
```

**library_internal.h:**

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_INTERNAL_H
#define LIBRARY_INTERNAL_H
#include "library.h"

struct myStruct {
    int some_x;
    void (*some_callback)(void);
};

#endif
```

---

Additional "best practice" notes:

- Don't hide pointers behind `typedef`s. Most C programmers are well aware that a pointer is part of the *declarator* and expect to explicitly *see* a pointer when there is one. Dereferencing something that doesn't *look* like a pointer will just cause confusion for others reading the code. You also might confuse consumers of your library into expecting a `myStruct_t` to exhibit *call-by-value* semantics.
- Don't define your own types with the `_t` suffix. At least in POSIX, this is reserved for the implementation (of the compiler/runtime). There's nothing wrong with defining a type of the same name as a `struct` tag.

Example with these additional suggestions:

**library.h:**

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

typedef struct myStruct myStruct;

#endif
```

**library_internal.h:**

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_INTERNAL_H
#define LIBRARY_INTERNAL_H
#include "library.h"

struct myStruct {
    int some_x;
    void (*some_callback)(void);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Instead of the `typedef` a simple `struct myStruct;` would just do as well.

Comment: @alk sure, if you don't need a typedef name. I prefer typedef names and it's closer to OPs original code :)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the C standard doesn't guarantee that a pointer to void has a *representation* that is compatible with a pointer to a struct! Thus:

```
typedef struct myStruct *myStruct_t;
typedef void *myStruct_t;
```

these two are not compatible and cannot be used in a strictly conforming program.

---

Another thing is that you usually shouldn't hide pointers, unless needed. Consider for example the `FILE` in the standard library. Its contents are not defined anywhere, but all the functions specifically return a *pointer* to it and accept a *pointer* to it.

You can even use a simple `struct` declaration, instead of definition:

```
struct myStruct;
```

Then external users can *define* a variable as a pointer to it

```
struct myStruct *handle;
```

Or if you wish to hide the fact that it indeed is a struct, use a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct myStruct myStruct;
```

Then the users of the external interface can define their variables simply as

```
myStruct *handle;
```